# Objective-c web form based authentication

Tags: objective-c, forms-authentication

So I am working on an iPad app that needs to talk to our company server to pull in some XML.  In a browser, when the user tries to first navigate to the site, they are redirected to an SSO form that generates a cookie that is saved.

Now my application may need to replicate this behavior and generate the cookie so we can pull xml data off various parts of the site.  I have never done anything like this before and there is very little documentation on the web so I am really looking for some general guidance.  So far I have tried doing something like this, [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704985/objective-c-asynchronous-web-request-with-cookies)

That works to return the web form, but where to go from there eludes me.  Does anyone have any ideas they would like to throw out?  Essentially all that I need to do right now is authenticate the user's credentials, and save that verification.  If there is an easier way to do that based on this template, I would definitely be open to suggestions.  Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i use for a lot of my networking is ASIHTTPRequest it is an API that is available, instead of trying to use low level sockets or the Apple APIs, with a decent guide and an active Google Group for questions. It can certainly handle xml requests as well as authentication. Here is a link to the site, [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it could be very useful.  The thing is, the way the app is set up now, it is almost like a portal to all of the functionality of the real software.  ie, the user logs in, and then selects the service they want to use.  All of these things are housed on the site.  All of the apps can run independently, it's just making the master login page that is the problem...

Comment: `ASIHttpRequest` is a good suggestion.  You might try `NSXMLParser` or  `TouchXML` for XML parsing.

Comment: Thanks guys, I am not sure if this will do what I want, but it is a start!