# Buffering Data First then Loading -iOS

Tags: ios, json, nsstring, buffer

I am planning to implement the following website.

user clicks play button, it first loads data then shows. How could I load all data first?

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load it asynchronously in the background and show a loading page to the user.

Comment: How could I load it in the background?

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704985/objective-c-asynchronous-web-request-with-cookies